# Visual Studio 15 Compilation Fails- clean project

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 15 Preview 3

When I create a new project (ASP.Net 5 "Empty" project) and press build all it fails to build. I get the following errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4063 The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.    WebApplication3 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 247 
Error   MSB4064 The "OutputLogFile" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. WebApplication3 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 261
```

Any suggestions please.  I have added no code, just created the project and pressed build.

Comment: For me the problems occur after upgrading my typescript version to 2.0.3. Downgrading to 1.8.11 fixes the problem.

Comment: Restarting visual studio would make it go away but it always seems to come back shortly after.

Comment: Should be a similar fix as this post: [“tsc.exe” exited with code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181699/tsc-exe-exited-with-code-1)

Answer (score 16):

If you check out the Output window contents after the build has failed, it should show the `targets` file path like this one:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets
```

Go ahead and remove the `OutputLogFile` attribute from the `VsTsc` element. This should make the build go through.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I worked around this by rolling back to VS2015.

Comment: I had the same problem with VS 2015 (Update 3) after installing VS 15 Preview. Removing the line 
      OutputLogFile="$(CompilerOutputLog)" did the trick.

Comment: I don't have that `OutputLogFile` parameter at all in my `Microsoft.TypeScript.targets` file, but I do have the same error.

Comment: There may be two lines with the attribute to remove. Removing worked for me as well, so + on this one.

Answer (score 13):

Downgrading "**Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild**" from version 2.0.6 to 1.8.11 removed the Compilation Errors.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. As it turns out the `VsTsc` task does support `OutputLogFile`. When I installed the newer TypeScript nuget packages (Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild) then it adds Microsoft.TypeScript.targets to the .csproj but neglects to remove the previous lines. Nuget will add lines similar to

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />

<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />
```

You have to manually removed the two lines pointing to :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! I'm using MVC 5, Angular 2, VS2015 update 3.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 15.6.3 and this did it to me too. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

The same errors were observed after installing Visual Studio Preview. Visual Studio 2015 Community addition Update 3 installed on the same computer also started getting the same errors, on a number of different Typescript solutions.  I could build the same solutions on an old computer 'Visual Studio 2015 Community addition Update 1'.   I then uninstall Visual Studio Preview. Errors still occurred on Visual Studio 2015 Community addition Update 3.   Also then uninstalled and reinstalled community addition and the problem was resolved, and could build the project.  I thought this solution may help others with the problem solving a more elegant solution  I do not have the reputation points to make a comment (where this belongs).

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with VS2015 Community and downloading the latest version of TypeScript (Version 2.1.5 posted 1/11/17) at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. TypeScript tools in VisualStudio 2015 and TypeScript packages attached to project had different versions that is why build failed with "The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters". I reinstalled TypeScript tools for VisualStudio 2015 (get older vertion) it solved my problem.

Comment: I don't even know how this answer seems to not have the attention of these guys. This is not a workaround. This is the correct solution. You are a savior Kate. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem.
For me the solution was:

- Remove "Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler" package
- Remove "Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" package

from installed packages.