# "tsc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm using **asp.net mvc** and **angular 2**. I updated Angular to version 2.1.1. Now when I compile, the `"tsc.exe" exited with code 1` error popped up. My Typescript files do not see the library files.

What could be the problem?

[image: typesript error],
[image: visual studio console].

## update

When I installed Typescrypt.Compiller 2.0.3 and Typescrypt.MSBuild 2.0.3, I got two new bugs:

1. "The "OutputLogFile" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property." and
2. The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input

## fixed

I removed from project TypeScript.Compiler and TypeScript.MSBuild. Don't now why i installed this. =) Then downloaded new version TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015 (TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe) and installed. It's solution my problem.

Comment: What version of TypeScript do you have installed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error messages as text, not as an images.

Comment: Error message: '"tsc.exe" exited with code 1' - it's all.

Comment: When i installed Typescrypt.Compiller 2.0.3 and Typescrypt.MSBuild  2.0.3, I got two new bugs: 1. "The "OutputLogFile" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property." and 2. The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed from project TypeScript.Compiler and TypeScript.MSBuild. Don't now why i installed this. =) Then downloaded new version TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015 (TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe) and installed. It's solution my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. First we would have to consider whether Visual Studio is the right way to build Angular 2 projects. If we determine that its the best approach then this is the solution I found to the error...

As it turns out the `VsTsc` task does support `OutputLogFile`. When I installed the newer TypeScript nuget packages (Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild) then it adds Microsoft.TypeScript.targets to the .csproj but neglects to remove the previous lines. Nuget will add lines similar to

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />

<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />
```

You have to manually removed the two lines pointing to :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Close VS and then download your TypeScript Tools.  You can get the tools here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593

When finished up VS and rebuild.  You should be good.